# How to tell inkscape not to change manually entered paths in xml editor?

Tags: inkscape, svg

When I draw paths in inkscape, I can use the mouse to drag handles and nodes around or I can use the XML editor to manually tweak the `d=` attribute of a `<path>` object.

However, if I edit the attribute and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the *Set* button, inkscape tries to "optimize" the path, this includes

- removing white white-space / newlines that I use for visual orientation on longer paths
- changing relative to absolute specifiers and vice versa (e.g. `l` to `L`)
- changing specifiers all together (e.g. turning an `l` into a `h`)

It does a similar thing with `transform` values, where it always mangles sequences of `scale` / `translate` / `rotate` instructions into a matrix (which is equivalent, but less edit friendly for humans).

**How do I tell inkscape to manually entered attributes alone.**

Comment: There's a setting in the preferences that switches between relative and absolute coordinates (Edit > Preferences > Input / Output > SVG Output).
The rest can only be kept if you don't use Inkscape for editing.
I think for the matrix separation, there is an extension somewhere.

So, do your drawing in Inkscape, and do your text editing in a text editor.

Comment: @Moini Yes, I actually just found the setting, too. It reduces the problem somewhat, but as you say, it doesn't address all problems. I use inkscape more to live-display a path while drawing it. I could change it in a proper editor and load up inkview or inkscape every time I touched it, but that strikes me as quite slow and unwieldy.